# Given an transition matrix what is the likelihood an observed markov chain was derived from this matrix

Tags: maximum-likelihood, stochastic-processes, markov-process, likelihood-ratio

To give a bit of background, I'm creating a MLE of a transition matrix from a set of empirical data. I'm then creating a simulation of the system that also produces a markov chain. I am looking for a means of comparing these models and thought of following the methodology provided here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86331/how-can-i-compare-two-matrices

My background is not in statistics and this explanation is a bit to succinct for me to grasp. Could someone help me understand this post or provide an alternative means of comparing to markov chains